# Why the update button of this code isn't working?

Tags: java, mysql

Here is the code for update the record in database which already entered. Program is running without errors. But after I update a existing record, it has not updated in db.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project", "root", "")) {
            String sql="update student set stName=?,gender=?,grade=?,subject=? where stNo=?";
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(stNo.getText()));
            pst.setString(2, stName.getText());
            pst.setString(3, gender.getText());
            pst.setString(4, grade.getText());
            pst.setString(5, gender.getText());

            pst.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record updated Successfully");
        }
    }
    catch(HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | NumberFormatException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

The thing is this code has already tested and I updated some existing records. But now it is not working.

Comment: I would say setInt(1) is not the stNo it is pointing to name.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter for the column `stNo` is the 5th and not the 1st in your statement:

```
    pst.setString(1, stName.getText());
    pst.setString(2, gender.getText());
    pst.setString(3, grade.getText());
    pst.setString(4, gender.getText());
    pst.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(stNo.getText()));
```

Comment: This is a "typo" question that probably should not be answered. It is almost certainly going to be closed, and it may be deleted after that, as it is not useful for a wide audience.

Answer (score 1):

Its logical error.... stNo is your 5th parameters .. thats why data are not updated.

```
pst.setString(1, stName.getText());
pst.setString(2, gender.getText());
pst.setString(3, grade.getText());
pst.setString(4, gender.getText());
pst.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(stNo.getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the order of parameters is not correct stNo is the fifth parameter not the first...
also to be able to trace the problem please consider to debug your code, test the query with given parameter on SQL workbench, phpMyAdmin and add Exception to catch statement and add e.printStackTrace() to catch body.